# Is there any implementation guide about AIML-OWL Integration?

Tags: rdf, owl, chatbot, aiml

So, i've done build an ontology using protégé and generate owl file, as far as i know owl is the rdf xml-based with more expressivity, and there are couples of paper that tells RDF can be integrated with AIML to build pattern matching chatbot with some kind of extensible knowledge such as

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228877414_Extending_knowledge_of_AIML_by_using_RDF

http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2007/Freese01/EML2007Freese01.html

But i can't get any clear explanation and easy understanding from what the paper talks about "what is" instead of "how to" intergrate between them, can someone who has more experience to give any guidance how to make it easier to understand its implementation.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking. You have an OWL ontology and saved it in RDF/XML syntax - and now? The ontology provides just a formal specification of some concepts in a given domain. What is your ontology about? And what is your chatbot supposed to do? I mean, it has to understand the human somehow, or not? How do you do this?

Comment: @AKSW I think OP wants to integrate this RDF file with AIML file which will match the patterns and send responses to the text requests.

Comment: I want to utilize my ontology (that have been generated to owl file) as a reference to construct any aiml pattern tag or template tag according to what has been explained from papers that i've attached its link.

Comment: Is the TO the same person that was asking the exactly same question here 5 days ago: https://www.chatbots.org/ai_zone/viewthread/3651/ ? or is it some university project that multiple people have to do? If not, at least there the is an answer to use the tool https://github.com/keiffster/program-y