# Integrate AIML with RDF

Tags: java, rdf, chatbot, aiml

I have created an A.L.I.C.E chatbot with Java. For that the possible questions and responses are added to an AIML file. For this chat bot I want to expand it's knowledge base from an ontology.

I have created a knowledge base with RDF formatted ontology and queried data through SPARQL.
Is there any method of integrating the RDF knowledge to the A.L.I.C.E chatbot?

Comment: you should use the search next time, was asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56070194/is-there-any-implementation-guide-about-aiml-owl-integration) ... I guess nothing has changed in the meantime, so one suggestion was to use this chatbot which supports RDF integration: https://github.com/keiffster/program-y/wiki/RDF  - also, there is some research paper around https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Extending-knowledge-of-AIML-by-using-RDF-Tzoua-Lua/b7108860ccc3a549225a8bcde4863250395f75f0

Comment: for you specific tool though you could ask the devs if there is some RDF support, if not I guess you have to implement it. Shouldn't be that difficult if you follow the other tool or the research paper ideas. Good luck, and don't forget to post some answer here once you found some solution